# How to know the number of input tags in a submitted form?

Tags: php, html

I've coding for adding input elements in a form when a button outside the form is clicked.

```
<?php
$i=0;
$maxid = isset($_POST['max_id'])?$_POST['max_id']+1:0;
print '<form action="search.php" method="post" ><input type="hidden" name="max_id" value="' . $maxid . '" /><input name="ad_field_button" type="submit" value="Add Field" /></form>';
print '<form action="results1.php" method="post" >';
print '<table border="0">';
for($i=0;$i<=$maxid;$i++)
   {
       // code for adding input elements;
   }
print '</table>';
print '<input name="ad_s_button" type="submit" value="Search" />';
print '</form></p>';
?>
```

I want to know the number of input element in the submitted form when button ad_s_button is clicked. Or how can I pass the 'max_id' value to the next page when ad_s_button is clicked. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can `count()` the number of items held within `$_POST` using `count($_POST)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or how can I pass the 'max_id' value to the next page when ad_s_button
>   is clicked.

You could use a hidden field in your form and store the max_id there.

```
<input type="hidden" name="max_id" value="<?php echo $maxid; ?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
print '<input type="hidden" name="Inputelements" value="'.$maxid.'">';
```

so you have a hidden field with the value u want

Comment: Yes, I want this value to pass with the second form in the code  @Xavjer

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` contanis all the submitted elements.

In your case count($_POST)-1 will give you the count of the input elements. -1 becuase there is a button(submit buttom) will also be there in $_POST

Answer (score 0):

You can also post array. For example:

```
<input type='text' name='request[name]' />
<input type='text' name='request[surname]' />
<input type='text' name='request[city]' />
```

And php part:

```
$request = $_POST['request'];
echo '<pre>'
echo var_dump($request);
echo '</pre>'
```

will produce

```
array(3){
  'name' => 'abc',
  'surname' => 'bcd',
  'city' => 'Somewhere'
}
```

you can then process form data easily, and also count input fields easily, using `count($request);`